# neo4j queries response time

Tags: indexing, time, neo4j, response

Testing queries responses time returns interesting results:

1. When executing the same query several times in a row, at first the response times get better until a certain point, then in each execute it gets a little slower or jumps inconsistently.
2. Running the same query while using the USING INDEX and in other times not using the USING INDEX, returns almost the same responses times range (as described in clause 1), although the profile is getting better (less db hits while using the USING INDEX).
3. Dropping the index and re-running the query returns the same profile as executing the query while the index exists but the query has been executed without the USING INDEX.

Is there an explanation to the above results?

What will be the best way to know if the query has been improved if although the db hits are getting better, the response times aren't?

Comment: Perhaps you can share your datamodel, query and profile. Then we can help you explain the results. There are a number of factors that influence runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand how a query executes is probably to use the [PROFILE](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html) command, which will actually explain how the database goes about executing the query.   This should give you feedback on what cypher does with `USING INDEX` hints.  You can also compare different formulations of the same query to see which result in fewer `dbHits`.

There probably is no comprehensive answer to why the query takes a variable amount of time in various situations.  You haven't provided your model, your data, or your queries.   It's dependent on a whole host of factors outside of just your query, for example your data model, your [cache settings](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-caches.html), whether or not the [JVM decides to garbage collect at certain points](http://www.dynatrace.com/en/javabook/impact-of-garbage-collection-on-performance.html), how full your heap is, what kind of indexes you have (whether or not you use `USING INDEX` hints) -- and those are only the factors at the neo4j/java level.   At the OS level there are many other possibilities/contingencies that make precise performance measurement difficult.

In general when I'm concerned about these things I find it's good to gather a large data sample (run the query 10,0000 times) and then take an average.  All of the factors that are outside of your control tend to average out in a sample like that, but if you're looking for a concrete prediction of exactly how long this next query is going to take, down to the milliseconds, that may not be realistically possible.

Comment: Thanks FrobberOfBits!

As you suggested, I am using the PROFILE command. The problem was that I couldn't really tell if the fact that there are less db hits (and better execution plans) equals to a faster query. From your experience, can I count on it although the non consistent response times?

Also played with the cache in the neo4j.properties file switched between soft to none but saw the difference only when running the query on the first time after restarting the neo4j server.I'll check about the JVM later on.

The average is a great idea, are the response times shown in the log?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by consistent.  Let's say a query normally takes 500ms.  I think you'll never get consistently 500 ms.  Maybe it'll be typical to see anything in the 300-600 range, with occasional outliers much bigger or smaller.   So in this sense, I don't think you should expect consistency.   But if the query should take 500ms, and you get something wildly different with a very large execution time range, that would be strange.  But again, it would depend on your data, your query plan, and what else your machine is doing.

Comment: Execution times aren't shown in the logs AFAIK.  This is something you'd build a simple script to measure.

Comment: Thanks again FrobberOfBits!
Currently the responses times (after few runs) are: ~20~150ms for both versions of most queries - which suits your description.
Playing with a local db and not the real one, the size of the data and no network delays might helped the speed.
The weird thing is that queries with less db hits, weren't faster but according to your sayings it make sense.
Guess, as you said, I'll have to run it a big number of times on the real db and measure the avg. Wonder if doing so will actually return better times for better execution plans.

Comment: I started to write up a blog post here, in case you want to give it a go: http://gist.asciidoctor.org/?dropbox-14493611%2Fblog%2Fadoc%2Fcypher_tuning_22.adoc

Comment: Hi Michael, cool blog, thanks for sharing your advice!
As to the USING INDEX, which you also mentioned, other than the improve of the db hits did you also see improvement in the query response time?

Comment: Yes, from several seconds to a few milliseconds. But it depends on the shape of the path and graph, if you fan out a lot from both sides it won't help.